# WAS 8.5 profile creation .Cannot run program "${env.SYSTEMROOT}\system32\CScript.exe"

Tags: websphere

I am trying to create new profile in Websphere 8.5 machine; but its giving me below exception

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "${env.SYSTEMROOT}\system32\CScript.exe" (in directory "was85\AppServer\profileTemplates\default\actions"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1059)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:631)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:834)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:576)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:617)
```

Machine configuration are 
Windows 7..64 bit...and Websphere 8.5.5

Comment: Are you using administrative user? Check if your user can access `C:\Windows\System32\CScript.exe` file (or wherever is your Win installed).

Comment: actually we are running as normal user mode.